# How to apply access roles to the controller extending AbstractRestfulController in zend

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework

I want to apply access roles to the different actions like GET action can be performed by all the users and POST or PUT action can be performed by only logged in users. I don't know how to apply different roles to different actions.

Answer (score 0):

In the mentioned scenario, i would do something like this using session Authorization.

FOR PUT AND POST ACTIONS

```
public function postAction/putAction
{
   if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
       //YOUR CODE
   }
}
```

FOR GET ACTION

```
public function postAction/putAction
{
       //YOUR CODE
}
```

This will ensure only logged in users can perform the post and put actions and all will be able to perform the get action.